Opening recycle bin takes 30 minutes or so on windows
I am on windows 10 with an SSD (the desktop is around 7 years old) - basically when I try to open my recycle bin it takes upwards of 30 minutes, and often just hangs. I am deleting a significant number of files, so it is very likely full of 5k+ files.
Furthermore, when I try to delete regular files it takes a long time as well.
I have tried to use chkdsk, but there appears to be no issues at all - furthermore, I have looked around but haven't found anything that fixes the problem unfortunately. Any help is much appreciate and please do let me know if I need to provide additional information.

If you don't mind forcibly deleting every user's Recycle Bin on that computer, you could utilize the following in an elevated command prompt:  rd /s /q c:$Recycle.Bin  ...and reboot once it's done.

See also https://www.windows-commandline.com/empty-recycle-bin-command-line/ for use of cleanmgr, too.

Are we talking about a HDD or SSD?  How full is the disk?

It is an SSD the desk has like 20% empty space

So it isn't a problem with low disk space.  Did you try the command that I recommended within the very first comment?  If this is simply a corrupt or problematic Recycle Bin, that command will delete it.  When you login again after a reboot, a clean/empty Recycle Bin will be subsequently created.

@JohnDoePython it has been more than a week since we heard from you.  Did you have an opportunity try the proposed solutions that we recommended?

Apologies, I actually managed to solve everything by running the deletion prompt from powershell - that was quick and managed to do the trick. Thanks a ton for the help!

Glad to hear it!  If that's the case it would be beneficial for the community if you submit your own answer to show us what solved the problem, and then return a few days later to officially accept it.
